# i cant run selenium 3.141 with the last version geckodriver 0.26 and firefox v 77 in python 2.7

Tags: python, linux, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I got the following exception:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

```py
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException:
invalid argument: can't kill an exited process
```

I checked all similar questions but it only worked with selenium 3.11, geckodriver 0.22 or higher and firefox v57.

My os is Linux Ubuntu 20.

Comment: Hi @Mauro, Please provide your selenium config/code where you are creating instance of browser.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal code to reproduce the problem. See more details on how to post a question at this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: thanks but finally i found the solutions, here in this link https://www.jianshu.com/p/265c0a5afe20